# Z-index on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a list that I made is slightly overlapping each element due to the line-height chosen. I would like to have it so that when I hover over each item, the hover animation overlays everything else cover it. I put the z-index  on the hover but the hover still stays below some parts. [image: Initial Unhovered] [image: Hovered]

```
.sidebar ul {
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 0;
line-height:20px;

}

a:hover {
color: #424242;
text-decoration: none;
background-color:#424242;
z-index: 100; !important
}
```

Comment: z:index only works if the element has a positioning context. Try adding `position:relative` to the link.

Comment: The correct `!important` syntax is `z-index: 100 !important;` (semi-colons go after `!important`). Anyway, you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[w3schools zIndex property description](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp):**

> The zIndex property sets or returns the stack order of a positioned element.
>
> Tip: A positioned element is an element with the position property set to: relative, absolute, or fixed.

You will need to set position to either "relative", "absolute" or "fixed" for your a:hover

Comment: ahhh i see. yup adding a relative worked. :D learning new stuff everyday.

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky, because when you tie the items close to each other you will lose the ability to hover them. Anyway, try this css below. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN8M8/)

Using the property `position` with `fixed` or `absolute` values will stack the items, which I believe is not your intentions to do so. That is why `relative` is your best friend here

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    line-height: 11px;
}

    ul a {
        z-index: -10;
        position: relative;
    }

li:hover a {
    color: #424242;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #424242;
    z-index: 100 !important;
}
```